# Spark Streaming StreamingContext error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hi i am started spark streaming learning but i can't run an simple application
My code is here

```
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming._
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://beyhan:7077").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
```

And i am getting error like as the following

```
scala> val newscc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
15/10/21 13:41:18 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spark-shell, and it seems like you do, you should not instantiate `StreamingContext` using `SparkConf` object, you should pass shell-provided `sc` directly.

This means:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://beyhan:7077").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
```

becomes,

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
```

Comment: thanks your reply your answer is correct.:) but i have another problem when i want to run this command on sbt package i am getting this error /MyApp.scala:20: object Streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.Streaming._

Comment: You should refer to [Spark Streaming Guide#linking](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html). Basically, add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.1" to your `build.sbt`. And please search before you ask!

Comment: You should also add it as a provided dependency, as the spark streaming libs are provided by spark itself and thus don't need to be included into the assembly jar

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you work in the Spark Shell.
There is already a SparkContext defined for you there, so you don't need to create  a new one. The SparkContext in the shell is available as `sc`

If you need a StreamingContext you can create one using the existing SparkContext:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
```

You only need the SparkConf and SparkContext if you create an application.

Comment: thanks your reply your answer is correct.:) but i have another problem when i want to run this command on sbt package i am getting this error /MyApp.scala:20: object Streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.Streaming._